# WordPress: is extending plugin allowed by GPLv2?

Tags: gpl-2, plugins

I would like to extend an existing plugin (for example [FileBird](https://wordpress.org/plugins/filebird)), to add some features, and later publish and sell it off...

But although the plugin's source-code can be simply downloaded from `WordPress.org` under `GPLv2`, the plugin has some registration and/or billing built-in...

Is it legal to modify the plugin, where it asks for purchasing it? or even completely removing that and make a free alternative (under another name of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first question was whether FileBird was really under GPLv2; they don't exactly go out of the way to make the license a salient.  But after some digging [it looks like](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/filebird/trunk/readme.txt) you're right.

That given, what you propose - removing the billing and registration hooks - is completely lawful.  You don't even have to use another name, though it would probably be kind of you to do so as it may reduce confusion.  You will of course need to release your version under GPLv2 also, which may impact on your plans to "*sell it off*".

Be prepared for the possibility of opprobrium: some people release software under copyleft licences, possibly without fully understanding that that empowers people to develop the code in ways they themselves would not choose to.  [They then get *very upset*](http://jedimark.net/2019/02/08/sleepyhead-project-shutdown/) when other people try to exercise the rights they've explicitly been given.  None of that, however, makes what you propose in any way unlawful.

Comment: Thanks, and of course selling it off would be problematic for an open-source project, although we always have the option of using Premium-marketing (like billing only for extensions, updates and...), but that requires our base-plugin to be worthy in the first place

Comment: @Top-Master note that even if your extensions and updates are only distributed to paying customers, they will also have to be distributed under GPLv2, so charging for those, too, may not work very well.

Comment: Is really any extension developed for a product which is published under `GPLv2` forced to be under `GPL` too? I mean, forcing `GPLv2` on plugins would be not very practical, no one would be able to create any plugin for any of such products (except when they do also use `GPL` as their license). for example, does that mean, we are legally NOT even allowed to develop any plugin for `WordPress` in the first place, except when we do publish the plugin under `GPL` too!!! have created another question at: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8080/is-gplv2-forced-upon-extensions